# Does the air cushion on which the original hyperloop will sit require energy constantly or not

Tags: classical-mechanics

Does the air cushion on which the original hyperloop idea envisioned by Elon Musk  require energy constantly to keep afloat, as the hovercraft does or would it be designed as the modern air suspension where energy requirement is once off, air is let into the  suspension cylinder, vehicle is floating in air then valves and seals take over.

Comment: I think you have some erroneous assumptions.  The hyperloop will operate under vacuum conditions, so any levitation must be magnetic.

Comment: https://www.tesla.com/sites/default/files/blog_attachments/hyperloop_alpha3.pdf

Comment: In my opinion, the hyperloop in the link is a "pie in the sky" conceptual design that way under-estimates cost of construction and operation, and over-estimates the engineering and maintenance challenges of maintaining a LOT of rotating equipment.

Comment: I did go on to read the entire article, and it basically answers my question. As Elon musk has proven time and time again, what seems like a pie in the sky even to our very best of experts, he achieves, and in spectacular fashion, even exceeding what he set out to do by magnitues, first deemed a pie in the sky, even